# KendoReact upload - passing file Id to React after saving file

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I'm a bit stuck with the kendo react upload control.

I need to customise the rendering of the kendo react upload control.
After the user upload the file, I want to save the file in database. Then I need to pass the database Id back to the client because if the user then wants to remove the file I also need to clear the database.

To give you an idea this is what I would like to achieve.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ghna5h

(When you start stackblitz open file app/main.jsx)

Is it possible?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I struggled with the same problem for about a week, then gave up. It is not possible with react control. I have sucessfully returned id when using jquery and vue upload controls though. In the end I just used the filename as id, combined with id of record I attached to.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular issue using a combination of the onStatusChange and onBeforeRemove events. The server's 'save' endpoint returns an id (responseUID) that can be accessed through the onChange event's response object. I set this id on the 'file' object. Then when you're removing the file I pass the responseUID along in the additionalData field which gets put into the POST body.

```
    const onStatusChange = (e) => {
        if (e.response) {
            const fileId = e.response.response.responseUID;
            // This does not deal with multiple or batch uploads.
            e.affectedFiles[0].responseUID = fileId;
        }
    };

    const onBeforeRemove = (e) => {
        e.additionalData.responseUID = e.files[0].responseUID;
    };

    return (
        <Upload
            batch={false}
            defaultFiles={[]}
            withCredentials={false}
            saveUrl="https://localhost/upload/save"
            removeUrl="https://localhost/upload/remove"
            onStatusChange={onStatusChange}
            onBeforeRemove={onBeforeRemove}
        />
    );
```